# How to build a web site or mobile app with a circular routing capability?

Tags: routing

Hoping this is an easy one...

I want to build a web/mobile app for a college project which allows the user to enter a start point and a distance to travel e.g. distance to travel = 6km and the site would then plot a 6km circular route which brings the user back to where they started without (if possible) backtracking on any of the route already travelled.

I've been looking at OpenStreetMap and OpenLayers or Leaflet.js.

I'm not sure if this explains it very well but I suppose the app might work by calculating a 3km "end" point with a 1.5km waypoint on the east and a 1.5km waypoint on the west. Prefer to use open source technology.

I'm new to this so appreciate advice.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! I strongly suggest reading the [FAQ](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) on how to ask questions such that they can be answered in a reasonable amount of time. That means doing some initial research on your own, sharing that research, making clear any requirements or limitations answers should follow, and generally framing the question within an answerable scope. Currently this question is far too broad IMO.

Comment: Also, if this is a programming question, consider http://stackoverflow.com instead of, or in addition to, this site.

Comment: Thanks blah238 - I'm new to the board and realised what the FAQ post was just as I posted so I will have a good mooch through it. I've been looking at OpenStreetMaps and leaflet.js for the mapping solution but yes - will also have a look on stackoverflow.com Thnks!

Answer (score 1):

BikeHub  already has an App (iPhone/Android) that has a leisure mode that includes circular routes

http://www.cyclestreets.net/blog/2011/04/29/bike-hub-leisure-routing/

**Bike Hub Site**
http://www.bikehub.co.uk/featured-articles/bike-hub-app-reviews-and-some-answers/
(with Video)

Forum
http://www.bikehub.co.uk/forum/